# Replacing a column using a SQL CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Here is my query:

```
select CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE is NULL THEN <do calculation>
            ELSE ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE END AS ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE,
            * 
from (<a table containing an ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE column>)
```

The calculation is working fine, the problem is the resulting table has two `ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE` columns, one from the original table and another that is added by the CASE statement. Is there a way to *replace* the `ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE` column in the original table entirely with the `ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE` column that's generated by my CASE statement?

Comment: Yes, avoid `*` and use explicit column names

Comment: yes..you have to `update` the table.

Comment: Yes.  List out all the *remaining* columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the retrieval of all columns in your table via the use of '*'.  Determine the actual columns you need from the queried table and name them explicitly in your select list, being sure to exclude ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE.

Many a DBA will tell the bane of their existence is a query that just grabs everything in site. SELECT * is rarely the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wante the replace the original value with calculated you could use 
the case when asi in you sample

```
  update my_table 
  set ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE = CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE is NULL THEN <do calculation>
                    ELSE ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE END
```

or simply and update  .. where

```
 update my_table 
  set ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE =  <do calculation>
  where ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE is null
```